# When i reload the page, the data from localStorage disapears

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a todolist, but i want de data to stand in the page when i reload. Im trying to work with local storage but im having problems with it. Im using setItem and getItem, but it isn`t working.

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("todoStorage");
    setTodos(JSON.parse(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("todoStorage", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, you have to add condition in use effect, if we have length of an array..then only update local storage

```
// Declare a state variable 'todos' and a function 'setTodos' to update it
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(null);

// First useEffect hook - runs after initial render and only once (empty dependency array)
useEffect(() => {
  // Retrieve data from local storage with the key "todoStorage"
  const data = window.localStorage.getItem("todoStorage");

  // Parse the retrieved data as JSON and check if it's an array
  const isArray = Array.isArray(JSON.parse(data));

  // Set 'todos' state based on whether the retrieved data is an array or an empty array
  setTodos(isArray ? JSON.parse(data) : []);
}, []);

// Second useEffect hook - runs whenever 'todos' state changes
useEffect(() => {
  // Check if 'todos' is not null and store it in local storage as a JSON string
  todos !== null && window.localStorage.setItem("todoStorage", JSON.stringify(todos));
}, [todos]);
```

Answer (score 0):

well guys, i found an indian youtuber that helped me with that, im gonna post the code that fix that problem for me:

```
   const getLocalStorage = () => {
  let todos = localStorage.getItem("todos")
  if(todos) {
    return (todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("todos")))
  } else {
    return []
  }
}

function App() {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState(getLocalStorage);

 useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("todos", JSON.stringify(todos))
 }, [todos])
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue you're experiencing could be related to the initial state of the todos array. When the component is first rendered, the useEffect that reads from localStorage runs, and if there is no data in localStorage, it sets todos to null (since JSON.parse(null) results in null).

To fix this issue, you can add a check to see if the data retrieved from localStorage is not null before setting the state. If it's null, you can initialize todos to an empty array. Here's how you can modify your code:

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    
useEffect(() => {
  const data = window.localStorage.getItem("todoStorage");
  if (data) {
    setTodos(JSON.parse(data));
  }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.localStorage.setItem("todoStorage",JSON.stringify(todos));
}, [todos]);
```

In this modified code, if the data retrieved from localStorage is not null, it will set the todos state with the parsed data. If the data is null, it will keep todos as an empty array. This way, even if there is no data in localStorage, todos will always be initialized as an empty array, preventing unexpected behavior when you reload the page.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).